# Meaning of "throe" in context ("throe inheritance")

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, archaicisms

I came across this passage in chapter 12 of David Eddings' *Pawn of Prophecy*:

> "Hail, greatest of Lords," she crooned, bowing deeply. "When thou comest into **throe inheritance**, remember that it was old Martje who first greeted thee."

[Source](https://sites.google.com/site/hellimyne/home/davadbm/belgariad/book-1-pawn-of-prophecy/chapter-twelve); passage above appears in the 5th paragraph from the bottom of the page.

What exactly is the meaning of "throe" in this context? The character Martje uses the archaic "thou" and "thee" so I immediately thought "throe" was another possessive pronoun, but I can't find any reference for "throe" taking on this sort of meaning. ("Thine" probably would have covered that.)

I'm only familiar with the word's meaning in the context of "death throes" - is it possible that this meaning (i.e. pain, suffering) is being borrowed to describe the main character's path to inheriting ... whatever he is supposed to inherit? PoP being fantasy, that wouldn't surprise me.

Googling this exact phrase tells me it appears later in the book... **Note** that I'm only on chapter 15, so please refrain from spoilers!

Also, I'm reading an electronic copy of the book in which I've noticed a handful of other typos, so I suppose it's possible that "throe" is supposed to be some other word altogether.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was meant to be "thine", as "thine" is used in this edition: https://books.google.com/books?id=rvRP9HRFCMUC&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a meaningless OCR error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a misprint.**

The grammatically correct word here would be "thine", [as used in the King James Bible, Psalm 28:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+28%3A9&version=KJV)

> Save thy people, and bless thine inheritance.

('Thy' would be used if the following word did not start with a vowel)

The word "throe" [does not have any accepted definition similar to this.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throe)

Comment: If this is a scanno, or even a typo, then *thy* is not the most likely. Firstly because *thy* is much shorter than *throe* and has a descender. *Thine* can be used the same as *thy* although it is more old fashioned and it can be easily misread as *throe*. But the KJV often uses *thine* before a vowel and *thy* before a consonant as in [9Save thy people, and bless thine inheritance: feed them also, and lift them up for ever.](https://biblehub.com/kjv/psalms/28.htm) as it sounds better so there are two reasons for thinking *thine* is more likely.